# Android SQLite error I can't recreate

Tags: android, sqlite

I had an error reported in the android market that I cannot recreate. The error was

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, Song, Number FROM HOLA.
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1454)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1338)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1293)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1373)
at com.example.program.DBase.fetchData(DBase.java:89)
at com.example.program.View.fillData(View.java:57)
at com.example.program.View.onCreate(View.java:29)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
... 11 more
```

HOLA is a user entered table. The code I use is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getLoc();
    setContentView(R.layout.notepad_list);
    db = new DBase(this);
    db.open();
    fillData();
    db.close();

}
```

and

```
private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
    Cursor c = db.fetchData(loc);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] { DBase.KEY_ONE, DBase.KEY_TWO };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2 };

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);

}
```

and lastly

```
public Cursor fetchData(String loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return ourDatabase.query(loc, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_ONE, KEY_TWO },
            null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

loc is a variable pointing to the current table. Any ideas why this happens? I tried entering data including a . and a , mentioned in the error, but I couldn'r get an FC.

EDIT adding my add table code

```
public long addTable(String loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ourDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + loc + " ("
            + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_2TBL
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_TWO + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_ONE + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_2TBL, loc);
    return ourDatabase.insert(loc, null, cv);

}
```

Comment: I noticed that I have about 40% of my downloads in foreign languages. From the table name HOLA, I'm guessing the user is using Spanish. My app isn't localized. Could that be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the user has entered "HOLA."(with dot) rather than just "HOLA".  That may be the reason app gave FC

Comment: That was it! any idea on how to prevent users from entering disallowed characters in the table name? The user entered tables store the "location" for the song list. Editing my post to include my add table code.

Comment: You could add a LoginFilter to your textbox and implement isallowed function where you can return true only to characters that are allowed